# Error in exchange property mapping to velocity template with Apache Camel upgrade 2.25+

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, velocity, camel-routes

I did Apache Camel velocity upgrade on my Spring boot application to 2.25.4
Now I am unable to access exchange properties from the velocity template. Just template is retrieved without values.

application works fine with org.apache.camel:camel-velocity:2.24.3 (2.25+ velocity libraries gives this error)

I am using org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.EscapeTool

Following are the relevant dependencies used:

```
"org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.25.4"
"org.apache.camel:camel-velocity:2.25.4"
"org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core:2.3"
"org.apache.velocity.tools:velocity-tools-generic:3.1"
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you added the `velocity-engine-core` dependency yourself?
According to [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-velocity/2.25.4) `camel-velocity` `2.25.4` seems to use `velocity-engine-core` version `2.0` so it's possible that `camel-velocity` version `2.25.4` is incompatible with `velocity-engine-core` `2.3`

Comment: Also have you tried to set the `allowContextMapAll=true`? According to the documentation by default only body and headers can be accessed .

Comment: Yes, I have added velocity-engine-core dependency. This is working as expected with camel-velocity:2.24.3, velocity-engine-core:2.3 and velocity-tools-generic:3.1

Only update is upgraded camel-velocity to 2.25.4

Comment: Included allowContextMapAll=true to the velocity route URL and this works, thanks @PasiÖsterman